# I'm question-blocked but the mobile app doesn't tell me this until I try to post

Tags: bug, post-ban, android-app

I have asked some bad questions in the past on Stack Exchange. So, when I try to ask a question through the website I get told I've hit the limit.

But when I go on the mobile application (Android), I can ask questions just fine.

**UPDATE**: I can't actually post and it just goes to the form. It notifies me I can't post after I press submit.

- I am using the same account on both sides.
- The error I receive is as follows:

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Is this a bug or some sort of intended feature?

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in to the same account in both places?

Comment: What is the error message you get when you post from your PC (I can see this being a per-IP ban on the PC, but the cell on another network is fine?)

Comment: @JoshCaswell same account, just checked.

Comment: @Patrice this is the error:
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: @misha130 then no... it's a bug indeed. There is a limit of questions from the same IP, so I figured maybe your PC at work is being hit by that (since other coworkers could also use Stack), and your cell isn't hit.... If THIS is the error message you get.... that's different. Thanks for being honest I guess? :P

Comment: I feel like I might have ruined it for all the other blocked ones too. Oh well

Comment: @misha130: Comments are meant to be temporary. Please [edit] your question to include the important information you have in the comments.

Comment: If you know you are question-blocked, why do you try to ask a question anyway??  Or is the real problem that you are getting your sock accounts mixed up?  Bummer.

Comment: Because I check if I am unblocked. Even though I am blocked I have desperate questions and I need answers. I have no other accounts

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you actually able to *post* a question?

I suspect the mobile app probably fails to check before showing you the "ask" form. Which means you'd be able to fill out the question, but it would be rejected when you tried to post it.

Not exactly the best experience, but hey it's mobile - you gotta give up *something* in exchange for the ability to post stuff while driving.

Comment: I am 90% sure I can post a question because I've done so in the past while being blocked. I sort of don't want to test it as to not get more banned for spamming or something

Comment: You are right, I can't post. Cheers

Comment: _"Not exactly the best experience, but hey it's mobile - you gotta give up something in exchange for the ability to post stuff while driving."_ Don't Stack Overflow and drive, kids!

Comment: Allowing a user to compose a post only to cheerfully tell them their efforts are wasted and results lost is actually rather bad. It this so troublesome to fix? Like, simply do not show the form in the first place?

Comment: My guess is that this information isn't readily available via the API, @ivan_pozdeev. It could be added, but keep in mind that q-bans are only applicable in a small number of cases, and that becomes even smaller when you consider mobile usage. So not a huge priority when compared to other areas where the mobile apps lag behind the normal site.

Comment: Remix OS is Android customized for desktop computers. Users are unlikely to be driving.

Comment: I get it's a joke, but the reference to driving freaks me out.